# Python Selenium get image name from website

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape a website for my project, but i'm having trouble with scrapping image names via Selenium from this [website](http://comparefirst.sg/wap/productsListEvent.action?prodGroup=whole&pageAction=prodlisting)

[image]

with the below code, I am able to use selenium to return me the `text` data from the website

```
results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.result_content")

for result in results:
    company_name = result.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").get_attribute("innerText")
    product_name = result.find_element_by_id('sProdName').get_attribute("innerText")
    product_paymode = result.find_element_by_id('paymode').get_attribute("innerText")
```

I was told to use `get_attribute("innerText")` because there are several items hidden, and `get_attribute("innerText")` would help me get the hidden items. (True enough, it works)

my question is: How do I scrape the `prod-feature-icon` class, to tell me if that picture is `active` or not??

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [find_element_by_class_name](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) ?

```
feature_icon = result.find_element_by_class_name("prod-feature-icon")
```

However it's worth noting that the object with this class name is actually a `UL` within it there are several images so you need to decide which image exactly you want to work with from that. Alternatively you could iterate through them with

```
for item in feature_icon.find_elements_by_tag_name('img'):
    print(item.get_attribute('src'))
```

of course this wouldn't still tell you whether the item is active or inactive because that doesn't seem to be dictated by the CSS but rather by the shading of the image

Comment: shouldn't it be `find_elements_by_class_name`

Comment: Well there are two methods, when you want to iterate through the whole set you use the plural, when you don't care about which element you get or you are sure there's only one, you use the singular

Comment: I've tried it, but it seems to print out `None` instead of the image name

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Its definitely getting me something! But it returns multiple rows of `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f556e2cc0f91051505a03ab078bbdb89", element="0.6230983186130168-646")>` Would it be better if i put in the website I'm trying to scrape?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the website. in the `result_container` class, I am trying to draw out the name of the `image` file in `product feature` to see if it is `active` or not

Comment: @e4c5 I've added the picture back as you asked. :) Link is also up there.

Comment: Thanks for this e4c5, I can actually just go through the link that is printed out and maybe use `regex` to separate which of those have the word `active` inside.

Comment: glad to have helped